# Play Framework The type ... is already defined

Tags: compiler-construction, types, model, playframework

```
when i try to run my Application it gives me following error:

Compilation error
The file /app/models/setting.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The type Setting is already defined
```

- I do have only one file "Setting.java", which is in the models directory
- the file is named "Setting.java" and not "setting.java" as the error message suggests
- i do not include any play modules

I am running play on windows. Is it possible that play has problems with windows' case insensitive? So it would first try to compile models/Setting.java and after that models/setting.java ??

What else could be the reason for this odd behavior?

/EDIT:
Since i wrote this question here i did not edit anything at my play application and i did not restart it. Now i just refreshed the page and the same error comes again - but with another model!!

```
The file /app/models/staticsite.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The type Staticsite is already defined
```

/EDIT2:
After a few page refreshes in the browser this error appeared:

```
The file /app/models/setting.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The public type Setting must be defined in its own file
```

The file IS named "Setting.java" and the class IS named Setting

Comment: can it be that you've forgotten package declaration?

Comment: each controller is in package controllers and each model is in package models...

Comment: Are you running from an IDE? If so have you refreshed your application settings with the appropriate command (i.e. play eclipsify) ?

Comment: I am not running from an IDE, but from windows' cmd: Play run Prototyp1

Comment: I think that @sdespolit was asking if you have a "package models;" inside your Setting class, not if it is inside the models folder.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thats what i meant to say. Package declaration is right in each class.

Comment: @user1070022 which version of play are you using? Is there something on your PATH or CLASSPATH that may be causing this issue?

Comment: Anybody reach a solution to this one? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

"The type  is already defined" exceptions can be raised when the issue is outside of the mentioned class. If your class name matches (case-sensitive) and it is defined in its own file, your next step is to find out what code has recently changed that references this class. For me, the issue was that my file, "utils.Utils.java", had been imported in another file via "import utils.Utils;" which really confused the compiler when I referenced "utils.Utils.someMethod()" in the code. I changed the line to "Utils.someMethod()" and the exception disappeared.

I probably should have come up with a better naming scheme. :/

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when you rename the class file that you try to compile. Simply re run the play frame work after you refract the class name. This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a `settings.java` and replaced it with `Settings.java`? Anyway, try `play clean`.

If that doesn't work, check very carefully that you don't have any problematic invisible characters in your file.

Comment: I already tried "play clean" and deleting the tmp folder manually. ... How o i look for such "invisible" characters? What do you mean?

Comment: For example, the correct space sign is mapped to Alt-32 on Windows. There's another space sign, mapped to Alt-255 on Windows, which seems like a space, but it's "wrong". Eclipse will also mark this as an error. On the Mac you can accidentally insert such a space when pressing Alt-Enter. You need a text editor that can display invisibles.

Comment: I use Eclipse. It does not show errors in my play app. However, if i create an error on purpose, it shows it. Therefore Eclipse is not broken or something and there should be no such problematic characters

Comment: Well then I guess you have to post parts of your code. I know I had this once, it was only something subtle...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working with settings.someProperty whithout declare the object "settings", and play is thinking it's a static method of the class "Settings" with an error in the capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while trying to resolve merge conflicts in git. I missed a change, and was getting this compiler error.

The issue was that I had a variable of type `ClassName` named `className`. The variable had been deleted but this particular line was still trying to access it. Instead of reporting that the `className` variable did not exist, Play did some black magic and ended up reporting the name conflict above: "`Type ClassName is already defined`". There was some kind of name conflict with the `ClassName` class and the `className` variable.

The fix was to just alter that line, removing the incorrect access to the old `className` variable. Then run `play clean` and restart your server.