# play2 compile error: DaifaTradeController is already defined as object DaifaTradeController

Tags: playframework

I have a problem that i cant resolve it, please give me a way.
I have defined some controller in play2 project that have a same name but in different packages. once it run ok , but today i was update some classes, and then it cause a compile error:

**DaifaTradeController is already defined as object DaifaTradeController**

There are two classes named DaifaTradeController, but they are in different packages, one in **controllers**, another in **controllers.daifa**,
To my confusion, I debug it ok on my ide. I use intellij idea.
but i was update to the servers(one is windows servier 2008 64bit, one is centos 6.5 64bit), it cause error.

i use source type to deploy it to the server, i use

> activator run

to run the project

Excuse my pool English, wish you can understand what i say, help me, thank you.

Comment: did you try `activator clean`

Comment: it also cause the compile error

Comment: did you check similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301490/play-framework-the-type-is-already-defined